# What is the collision resolution mechanism for v8's associative array?

Tags: hashmap, associative-array, v8, hash-collision

Which mechanism does it use form the following?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution

Answer (score 2):

Open addressing with quadratic probing (reference: [source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/v8/src/objects.h?q=NextProbe%20package:%5Echromium$&l=3360)).

Note 1: Not everything that acts like an associative array is actually implemented as a hash table under the hood. In particular, small/dense arrays like `[3, 1, 4, 1.5]` are backed by an actual array (similar to a C array) for fast index-based access.

Note 2: The answer to this question may or may not change over time if/when the team experiments with alternative implementations. For example, open addressing requires relatively low load factors in order to provide quick accesses; it would be interesting to find an implementation that's more memory efficient (without being slower).